# Is there a trick to get the Firefox's Devtools (developer tools) debugger to pause JavaScript using the keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, javascript, debugger

When the Firefox Devtools (developer tools) Debugger pane is open, you are supposed to be able to press the <kbd>F8</kbd> keyboard key to pause JavaScript.

I find that this rarely works on complicated websites (it works fine on simple websites like Stack Exchange and StackOverflow).  Usually, the only way I can get Firefox to pause is to use the pointing device (trackball, mouse, etc.) to click the `pause` button in the Firefox Devtools GUI.  The problem with this is that it requires removing the cursor from the web browser viewport, which results in HTML elements losing focus.

Is there a trick/secret to getting the Firefox Devtools debugger to pause using the keyboard?

Comment: idk if this could be like on Mac, F8 is either 'true' F8, or 'play/pause [music, iTunes etc]' depending on which way the system pref is set. Opposite behaviour is achieved by adding Fn.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the idea.  I have F8 set to be the real F8.

Comment: If you would like to stop at a precise spot and can modify the JavaScript, you could use the [debugger command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger).

Comment: A trick that can sometimes be utilized: add a break point for some event. For example, if some tooltip you're interested in appears whenever the user clicks on something (but using a breakpoint on the DOM is not convenient), you can add breakpoints on mouse events. Under the "Pause" button, go to: Event Listener Breakpoints > Mouse > `click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @andrybak 's comment has really helped me do this, I'll add it as a full answer.

1. Open your site and go to the page / situation where you want to inspect the tooltip or other mouse dependent event.
2. In Firefox open the Developer Tools and go to the Debugger Tab. (called Sources in Chrome)
   Now navigate
3. Open 'Event listener Breakpoints'
4. Filter on 'mouse' (as shown below)
5. Select 'click' or if that triggers too often, 'dblclick' for Double Click.
6. Go to your site and trigger the event (hover over your element with a tooltip).
7. Now the debugger will break and you can inspect your site.

[image]